# Searching an item that is stored with multiple names concatenated with ** in mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to perform a search of my database in PHP using values containing ** to separate different values. One example my database is:

GS 300**GS3000

I want to search for values in my db with either GS 300 or GS3000.

My script is:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(parts_cats.Part_Type) FROM parts_cats WHERE stock.Item_Specifics_Type IN ('$ids') AND stock.stock_item!='' and Make='$Make' AND Model LIKE  '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($Model) .  "%'"
```

Currently the search works fine for non-double asterick values (E.g. if searching for G3 500) but it returns no results for GS 300**GS3000.

Comment: try an explode query

Comment: check in the database to see how it was stored.. Did you escape it also when you put it in the database?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis Stored in the database as GS 300**GS3000 (VARCHAR 50)

Comment: So you are sure that $Model is exactly the same as what is in the database?? Can you try a different delimiter when you store it - like dash? Also did you make sure you don't have extra spaces (the inputs are trimmed) ?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis the if I echo the query I get:

SELECT DISTINCT(parts_cats.Part_Type) FROM parts_cats LEFT JOIN stock on parts_cats.Part_Type=stock.Item_Specifics_Type WHERE stock.Item_Specifics_Type IN ('') AND stock.stock_item!='' and Make='Lexus' AND Model LIKE '%GS 300**GS3000%'

Comment: Item_Specifics_Type IN is empty btw.. is that the way supposed to be?

If this is exactly what you have in the database
try Model='GS 300**GS3000'. Does this work?

Comment: Also try my query in the answer and tell me if this works by splitting the two models ... try running the queries in phpmyadmin if you have it before trying the same queries in PHP

Comment: @MichailMichailidis I removed the Item_Specifics_Type IN because it was a long string. That works ok. If I query the database in SQL it doesn't work either. Work if I try Model='GS 300' or Model='GS3000'

Comment: you mean if you try Model='GS300' or if you try in a separate query Model='GS3000' ?? That shouldn't work that means that you haven't stored the Model as you think?? These are exact results so it shouldn't return anything..

Comment: @MichailMichailidis in the database I have some items stored as Model='GS 300' and some Model='GS3000'. I want the query to search both these options. So I created another table which has the 'friendly name' (I.e GS 300) and the search term 'GS 300**GS3000'

Comment: I don't get it .. why would you use another table and concatenate all those values?? if that is the case and you have ONE entry with all the possible names separated by asterisks in all of those items then my second query should work and can be genralized for any number of search terms/models... else you just use a WHERE Model='ModelOne' OR Model='ModelTwo' in the original table and will get all the items you need

Comment: @MichailMichailidis The second table is used to store values that are used in a dropdown list: $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Model,SearchModel FROM Make WHERE Make='$Make' ORDER BY Model ASC") 
 or die(mysql_error());

   while($tier2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
  
  {
     echo '<option value="'.$tier2['SearchModel'].'" >'.strtoupper($tier2['Model']).'</option>';
  }

SearchModel would be GS 300**GS3000 where as Model would be GS 300. When the user searches the stock database it needs to search for the values in SearchModel (if more than one separated by **)

Comment: The problem is the stock database is updated by different people who have different ways of categorising parts - some will use GS 300 and some will use GS3000. It is an external script so I can't force the user to input correctly either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64328/discussion-between-tomantford-and-michail-michailidis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find either one or the other Model you should do (although very expensive). I don't know what the ** are and how you have stored things in the database...

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(parts_cats.Part_Type) 
    FROM parts_cats 
    WHERE stock.Item_Specifics_Type IN ('$ids') 
       AND stock.stock_item!='' AND Make='$Make' 
       AND ( Model LIKE  '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($ModelOne) .  "%'
             OR  Model LIKE  '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($ModelTwo) .  "%')"
```

or the resulting query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(parts_cats.Part_Type) 
    FROM parts_cats 
    WHERE stock.Item_Specifics_Type IN ('$ids') 
       AND stock.stock_item!='' and AND='$Make' 
       AND ( Model LIKE  '%GS 300%'
             OR  Model LIKE '%GS3000%')
```

Edit:

Ok what I would do is have a table with fields like
`id concatNames` and have entries like `5, GS 300**GS3000` in it.. 
Then you get whatever the user inputs and you use the query I wrote above.. did you try it yet?

You can have the user input a string like this one:

```
$str = "something**something2**something3";
```

then you can it to an array using

```
$array = explode("**",$str)
```

or you could have multiple `<input>`s that the user could put things separately in.

In either case you have an $array of all the different values..

then you construct dynamically the WHERE part of your query as

```
"AND (Model Like '%".$array[0]."%' OR  Model Like '%".$array[1]."%' OR Model Like '%".$array[2]."%')"
```

This will work even if the user inputs `GS300`,`GS3000` alone or `GS 300**GS3000` or `GS3000**GS 300`

Comment: I think this is the right way forward, but how is the best way to explode the string with the ** as a separator?  - @$values =  explode("'**'",$Model);

Comment: `$array = explode("**",$string);`
Then you incrementally build the query with a loop over the $array see above my query ;)

Comment: @tomantford - This query is quite expensive. You may want to have a fulltext index for this field with the concatenated names or even better move the information in something like Lucene/ElasticSearch so that you can use the regular expression queries you are using now with better performance

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
...
AND ( Model LIKE  'SEARCHTERM%' OR  Model LIKE '%**SEARCHTERM%' )
```

SEARCHTERM can be GS3000, for example.